# Compilar Pango: Unknown variable pango_gir

Tags: compilar, pango

Estoy tratando de compilar *Pango*:

Comando:

```
./make-release.sh
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
docs/meson.build:25:0: ERROR: Unknown variable "pango_gir".
```

Final del registro de la consola:

```
Executing subproject gi-docgen 

gi-docgen| Project name: gi-docgen
gi-docgen| Project version: 2021.7
gi-docgen| Program python3 (jinja2, markdown, markupsafe, pygments, toml, typogrify) found: YES (/usr/bin/python3) modules: jinja2, markdown, markupsafe, pygments, toml, typogrify
gi-docgen| Program gi-docgen.py found: YES (/pango/pango/subprojects/gi-docgen/gi-docgen.py)
gi-docgen| Configuring gi-docgen.pc using configuration
gi-docgen| Build targets in project: 623
gi-docgen| Subproject gi-docgen finished.

Dependency gi-docgen from subproject subprojects/gi-docgen found: YES 2021.7
Configuring config.h using configuration
Configuring pango-features.h using configuration
Program glib-mkenums found: YES (overridden)
Program g-ir-scanner found: NO
Program help2man found: NO
Program gi-docgen.py found: YES (overridden)
Configuring pango.toml using configuration

docs/meson.build:25:0: ERROR: Unknown variable "pango_gir".

A full log can be found at /pango/pango/release_build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

¿Cómo reparo este error?

Answer (score 0):

La solución es, primero configurar con `meson` y luego compilar con `ninja`:

```
meson build
ninja -C build
```

En este caso el parámetro `-C` hace que se compile en la carpeta `build`.